# How to set 'src' to resource root in webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, path, webpack-encore

I have a react application, with custom webpack config (webpack-encore).

How can I set 'src' folder as resource root.
Ex:

I want to use

```
import 'components/someComponent.jsx'
```

instead of

```
import '../../components/someComponent.jsx'
```

Folder structure:

1. -app
2. --src
3. ---components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is adding like this in webpack config.

```
module.exports = {
 // ...
 resolve: {
  modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src')]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create some alias and then use a shorter path

```
let config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
config.resolve.alias["~"] = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src');
module.exports = config;
```

Now your import will look like

```
import SomeComponent from '~/components/someComponent.jsx'
```